# SLES 12.5 installing Python 3.9 from source

Tags: python3, sles

I've tried with

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.4/Python-3.9.4.tgz
tar xvzf Python-3.9.4.tgz
```

moved into the source directory

```
./configure
make
```

Then, after many lines, I receive an error

```
Could not build the ssl module!
Python requires an OpenSSL 1.0.2 or 1.1 compatible libssl with X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host().
LibreSSL 2.6.4 and earlier do not provide the necessary APIs, https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable/issues/381
```

I don't understand what to do because I checked

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2p-fips  14 Aug 2018
```

and

```
openssl-1_1 version
OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
```

and also, from root:

```
Reading installed packages...

S  | Name                       | Summary                           | Type
---+----------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------
i+ | libgnutls-openssl27        | The GNU Transport Layer Securit-> | package
i  | libopenssl-1_0_0-devel     | Development files for OpenSSL     | package
i+ | libopenssl-devel           | Include Files and Libraries man-> | package
i  | libopenssl1_0_0            | Secure Sockets and Transport La-> | package
i  | libopenssl1_0_0-32bit      | Secure Sockets and Transport La-> | package
i  | libopenssl1_1              | Secure Sockets and Transport La-> | package
i  | libxmlsec1-openssl1        | OpenSSL crypto plugin for XML S-> | package
i  | openssl                    | Secure Sockets and Transport La-> | package
i  | openssl-1_0_0              | Secure Sockets and Transport La-> | package
i+ | openssl-1_1                | Secure Sockets and Transport La-> | package
i+ | python3-pyOpenSSL          | Python wrapper module around th-> | package
```

Any ideas? Is it not possible to use python 3.9 on SLES 12.5? What is the maximum version I can have? (of course I've already the native 3.6 from zypper)

Maybe I should configure the root directory of openssl but I'm not sure where is it exactly

```
 which openssl-1_1
/usr/bin/openssl-1_1
```

Is it `/usr/bin` ? (I don't think so)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of `openssl-devel` that you have installed on the system isn't recent enough to build Python 3.9. You are going to run into this issue with many of the packages containing the development libraries that you need because you are running SLES 12 which only has version 1.0.0 whereas Python 3.9 requires a minimum of 1.0.2 and preferably 1.1.

The only thing that you can do is to build Openssl 1.0.2 or 1.1 from source and add it to your environment. You'll need to do the same with any other packages that are needed that aren't recent enough on your system. SLES 12 is still supported but it's not going to have the latest packages for more recent software such as Python 3.9.

Comment: Ok, where can I download the source of Openssl 1.1 from? `wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1k.tar.gz` is it correct?

Comment: I've just installed the above but I'm still failing to configure and make python (btw not sure which is the correct dir to pass to --with-openssl= for the configuration)

Comment: You can find it by using Google. You can either use the directory into which you compiled Openssl via `--with-openssl=/path/to/openssl` or by adding it's binary and library directory to your respective `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: I did it but with no luck till now... I'm still double checking

Comment: The most difficult part for me was libffi, for python I had to configure `--ldflags
 -L/usr/local/lib64` and finally I had to `pip3.9 install gnureadline` and not readline... I can't believe it: it looks like it is working!)

Answer (score 1):

Only for the records of a few details (when I'll have to repeat the process on a new snapshot).

When I tried to configure python3.9 with

```
./configure --prefix=$PY_HOME --with-openssl=/path_toopenssl/openssl-1.1.1k/apps
```

it was not enough likely because I had another old openssl already in the PATH, so I finally resorted to prioritize the correct path

```
export PATH=/path_toopenssl/openssl-1.1.1k/apps:$PATH
```

Then I had a lot of issues with libffi, so I guess it's worth to note that after

```
git clone https://github.com/libffi/libffi.git
```

and usual

```
./autogen.sh
.configure
zypper in makeinfo
make
make install
```

the tricky part for me was

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64
export LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib64
./configure --prefix=$PY_HOME PK_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig --with-system-ffi=/usr/local/lib64 LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib64
make
make install
```

At this point `pip3.9` could fail with `No module named '_posixsubprocess'`, that can be solved by installing

```
zypper in python3-curses
zypper in python-curses
zypper in ncurses
zypper in ncurses-devel
```

The above was not even all, since `pip39 install readline` was crashing and in conclusion I setup instead `pip3.9 install gnureadline`

It looks like it is working now :-)